# C++ Heap Corruption: Local heap variable causing issues

Tags: c++, heap-memory, heap-corruption

I am working on some simple terrain with DirectX9 by manually assembling the verts for the ground.

On the part of my code where I set up the indices I get an error though:

Windows has triggered a breakpoint in test.exe.

This may be due to a corruption of the heap, which indicates a bug in test.exe or any of the DLLs it has loaded.

Here is the part of my code that is giving me problems, and I'm almost 100% sure that it is linked to my indices pointer, but I delete it when I'm finished... so I'm not sure what the problem is.

```
int total = widthQuads * heightQuads * 6;
DWORD *indices = new DWORD[totalIdx];
for (int y = 0; y < heightQuads; y++)
{
    for (int x = 0; x < widthQuads; x++)
    { //Width of nine:
        int lowerLeft = x + y * 9;
        int lowerRight = (x + 1) + y * 9;
        int topLeft = x + (y + 1) * 9;
        int topRight = (x + 1) + (y + 1) * 9;
        //First triangle:
        indices[counter++] = topLeft;
        indices[counter++] = lowerRight;
        indices[counter++] = lowerLeft;
        //Second triangle:
        indices[counter++] = topLeft;
        indices[counter++] = topRight;
        indices[counter++] = lowerRight;
    }
}

d3dDevice->CreateIndexBuffer(sizeof(DWORD)* total, 0, D3DFMT_INDEX16, 
    D3DPOOL_MANAGED, &groundindex, 0);
void* mem = 0;
groundindex->Lock(0, 0, &mem, 0);
memcpy(mem, indices, total * sizeof (DWORD));
groundindex->Unlock();

delete[] indices;
```

When I remove this block my program runs OK.

Comment: not sure what Lock does, but void* mem = 0 followed by memcpy(mem,... does not seem right

Comment: Try to remove more blocks... Where's `counter` defined?

Comment: Doesn't your debugger tell you the line and instruction that failed along with what memory it tried to access?

Comment: Just to make sure, 'totalIdx' is the same as 'total' ? I do not see its declaration / assignment.

Comment: @stijn: That's correct, Lock method returns a valid pointer to memory which was created in the previous CreateIndexBuffer call.

Comment: I can't see where you clear `counter`, maybe that's causing the problem.

Comment: Yes, I forgot to reset my counter to zero after my vert set up. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code you've given looks OK - with one caveat: the initial value of `counter` is not in the code itself. So either you don't start at `counter = 0`, or some other piece of code is stomping on your `indices` buffer.

That's the beauty of heap corruptions. There is no guarantee that the bug is in the removed portion on the code. It may simply hide the bug that exists somewhere else in your code.

Comment: I do set the counter to 0 before this block. Here is the entire function:

Comment: Ahhh wait, I forgot to set it back to 0 after my vertices call. Thanks for the help!

Comment: +1 for your final paragraph.  I once had heap corruption in the `vector<>` destructor.  I *knew* it wasn't a problem with the standard library.  But it told me to look for array index problems, which is what was really happening.

Answer (score 0):

```
int total = widthQuads * heightQuads * 6;
DWORD *indices = new DWORD[totalIdx];
```

Shouldn't you be doing "new DWORD[total];" here?